# My first full node - no bitcoin.conf

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

So I am in the process of downloading the blocks after installing bitcoin on my ubuntu server. I have followed the guide on https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node.

Everything is working correctly. Blocks are downloading just fine to ~/.bitcoin/blocks. bitcoin-cli commands are working without error.

If I switch users and I try to issue a bitcoin-cli command naturally I get `"Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set."`

However when using the correct user where cli commands do work, there is still no bitcoin.conf file inside ~/.bitcoin/ As the node is downloading the blocks and the cli commands work I assume there must be a conf file - yet its not where every single document and support answer claims it will be.

I have tried `find . -name "bitcoin.conf"` in the ~/.bitcoin directory as well as user ~/ and in /etc all return empty. Where else could this file possibly hide? If it doesn't exists why would I still be downloading blocks and able to issue cli commands?

I am aware this question has been asked countless times but i cant find any answers relating to the fact the node is working and cli commands are working.

Comment: With the user where bitcoin-cli does work, you can try running `strace bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` and read the output to see which path it is reading `bitcoin.conf` from. For example, I can see `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3` in my local output.

Comment: well now i am super confused as that returns `open("/home/admin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` and yet i can still issue commands like `bitcoin-cli getnetworkhashps` and `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` without any errors.

Comment: Do you have a `/home/admin/.bitcoin/.cookie` file?

Comment: yes i do have ha file, i has a single line in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't explicitly specify any RPC credentials, bitcoind will autogenerate them for you and store the password in the `$DATADIR/.cookie` file.

You can then use the username `__cookie__` along with the password from that file.

Comment: Note that the contents of that file will change every time you restart Bitcoin Core. If you have a need for accessing your bitcoind in any setting other than the local user with bitcoin-cli, you should really create a bitcoin.conf file with a static username/password (look up rpcauth).